# adb | grep | cut not showing result... but cat | grep | cut is ok

Tags: android, shell, grep, adb, cut

Having some issue on using adb, grep and cut. I have a command below

```
adb logcat | grep MYTEXT
```

this has result of several text that has ":" separating them.

If I use the below to remove text before ":", it doesn't work.

```
adb logcat | grep MYTEXT | cut -d':' -f 2-
```

However if I first dump into a file and then do the same. It works.

```
adb logcat > mylog.out
cat mylog.out | grep MYTEST | cut -d':' -f 2-
```

I can use this approach as workaround, but I would prefer not to need to dump to mylog.out first as temporary step in my script.

Anyone to enlighten? Thanks!

Comment: `adb logcat` might be sending its output to standard error instead of standard output. Does `adb logcat >/dev/null` still show output? Does `adb logcat 2>/dev/null` show nothing? If that's the case then you want `adb logcat 2>&1 | ....`.

Comment: `adb logcat >dev/null` shows nothing. `adb logcat 2>/dev/null` shows the result.

Comment: Then it is sending to standard output and your `adb | grep | cut` pipeline should work identically to going through the file. Is `MYTEXT`/`MYTEST` a typo in this question or the problem? Also what does "doesn't work" mean exactly? Is some output missing? Is all output missing? Is `cut` not cutting?

Comment: I literally copy and paste to ensure MYTEXT has no typo, and the cut function is working as it is. So it's odd it doesn't work when directly use adb logcat (perhaps adb logcat is a process that is on-going... and not cat file.txt that ends?.. the only guess of different between the two)

Comment: Ongoing data isn't a problem for `grep` or `cut` but buffered data could be. How much data are we talking about coming from `adb` and making it through `grep`? Is the problem that you don't get any output at all? Does the "not working" version end or hang?

Comment: It works. It's the output from Android Phone device. It's basically a log dump while we are connected to the phone.

Comment: What works? What did that mean?

Comment: Sorry for not reply to last question, the adb is not hanging, but continue processing. If we just run `adb logcat`| grep MYTEXT`, it will continue process and just show rows with MYTEXT.

Comment: And then if you pipe that to `cut` do you not see any output or does the `cut` just not `cut` the lines correctly? If you pipe the `adb | grep` output to a file can you `cat | cut` that file? Can you show us some representative lines that failed to work correctly in the direct pipeline but do work if you put those same lines in a file? (Use `adb | tee test.txt | grep | cut` to get the lines in both the file and the pipeline for better testing.)

Comment: Thanks Etan for helping on. I tried the 'tee' version. Not working as well. Put it this way, I tried ```adb logcat |  cut -d':' -f 2-```, that works. I tried ```adb logcat | grep MYTEXT```, that works. But when I combine both grep and then cut, it doesn't work. But if cut comes first before grep, that works. (I can't use this though, as I want to eliminate the keyword used in the grep).

Comment: The `tee` version was to get *identical* output passed through `grep | cut` directly and manually with `cat test.txt` to see if the results were the same. Can you try that? I see no reason why `grep` could cause this problem (other than buffering, have you tried the `--line-buffered` option, though I think that's for input). Does `adb logcat` terminate on its own or run forever? Have you let the `adb | grep | cat` version run for a long time (in case `grep` isn't spitting out a lot of information and buffering is the problem)? Using `unbuffer adb | unbuffer grep | cut` might also help.

Comment: adb logcat doesn't termintate itself. It gets terminate when I pull the USB cable away or explicit disconnect it. After did that, the result shows. Indeed I guess grep is not passing it's result to cut until the process is completed. Looks like we're getting closer to the solution..  Is there a way to force grep to pass the result over to cut?

Comment: That's almost certainly a buffering issue and not a completeness issue. How much data is supposed to be making it through grep? If it isn't enough then the buffer won't flush and `cut` won't see anything. Try the `--line-buffered` option to `grep` and `unbuffer grep` (alternatively `stdbuf -o 0 grep` if you have `stdbuf`) in the pipeline and see if that helps.

Comment: Cool, that works! Thanks!! ```adb logcat | grep --line-buffered MYTEXT | cut -d':' -f 2-```. You want to put in the answer? I'll give an upvote and tick to the answer. If not, I'll post the answer :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming no typos (`MYTEXT`/`MYTEST`) or other similar issues are involved here then this is likely related to buffering of data and volume of data.

Telling `grep` to buffer its output by lines with the `--line-buffered` option will probably help here.

```
adb logcat | grep --line-buffered MYTEXT | cut -d':' -f 2-
```

As might using the `unbuffer` or `stdbuf` utilities.